# Sending Email with php / own seerver

Tags: php, content-management-system, email-validation

I'm wondering how you send a mail with the data filled in in a form. I have read that you can't adjust the php code, to prevent the mail entering the spam folder.

I have read that the server, which you send it from, responsible is for this.

I'm making a CMS on a server from school , for a school project. How can i fix the server settings or something to prevent that the email with register data goes to the spam folder.

Just like facebook (if you register you get a validation link in your mailbox), how did they prevent that the mail doesn't enter the spam folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam

Comment: search on [Gooogle](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+avoid+email+going+to+spam&revid=703371480)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'd recommend you to use something like [Mailgun](http://mailgun.com). They take care of all that stuff so that you can focus on your app.